# Jquery div class not lining up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, alignment

Under the Products tab I select the first option, however when I try to line up the data in vertical columns (9 check boxes in each column) it generates a space instead of align the group a and group b columns.

I believe the syntax is class="ui-grid-a or class="ui-grid-b, which I used. I see other examples on various sites but that code does not seem to work with my script.

How can I get these to align correctly?

Thanks.

```
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
  <h1>FirePlace and BBQ Center</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
      <fieldset data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">

<div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Contact Information</h3>
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

      </div>
      <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Products</h3>
        <select id="model">
<option id="select" value="0">Please Select Fire Place</option>
<option id="DXV35_III" value="1">Mendota DXV 35 DeepTimber Fire III Direct Vent Gas Fireplace</option>
<option id="DXV45_III" value="2">Mendota DXV 45 DeepTimber Fire III Direct Vent Gas Fireplace</option>
<option id="DXV35" value="3">Mendota DXV 35 Time Fire Direct Vent Gas Fire Place</option>
    <option id="DXV42" value="4">Mendota DXV 42 Direct Vent Gas Fireplace</option>
</select>

        <div data-role="content"id="div1" style="display:none;" >

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">



                <label for="DXV35_1">Millennia Black</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_1" value="DXV35_1">
          <label for="DXV35_2">Millennia Classic Brass</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_2" value="DXV35_2">
          <label for="DXV35_3">Millennia Full Brass</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_3" value="DXV35_3">
          <label for="DXV35_4">Wellington</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_4" value="DXV35_4">
          <label for="DXV35_5">Andover Doors & Faceplate</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_5" value="DXV35_5">
           <label for="DXV35_6">Prairie Doors & Faceplate</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_6" value="DXV35_6">
           <label for="DXV35_7">Deerfield (outside fit only)</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_7" value="DXV35_7">
           <label for="DXV35_8">Victoria Black</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_8" value="DXV35_8">
           <label for="DXV35_9">Victoria Gold</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_9" value="DXV35_9">
           <label for="DXV35_10">Tuscany Black</label>
           </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_10" value="DXV35_10">
           <label for="DXV35_11">Tuscany Gold</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_11" value="DXV35_11">
            <label for="DXV35_12">Bentley Black Arch Screen Doors</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_12" value="DXV35_12">
           <label for="DXV35_13">Bentley Vintage Iron Arch Screen Doors</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_13" value="DXV35_13">
          <label for="DXV35_14">Bentley Gold Arch Screen Doors</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_14" value="DXV35_14">
          <label for="DXV35_15">Bentley Antique Copper Arch Screen Doors</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_15" value="DXV35_15">
          <label for="DXV35_16">Bentley Gun Metal Arch Screen Doors</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_16" value="DXV35_16">
          <label for="DXV35_17">Bentley Swedish Nickel Arch Screen Doors</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_17" value="DXV35_17">
          <label for="DXV35_18">Andover/Prairie Doors & Faceplate Overlay (See Pricing Sheet)</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_18" value="DXV35_18">
          </div>
          </div>



<div data-role="controlgroup" id="div3" style="display:none;">
                <label for="DXV35_1test">Millennia Black test</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_1test" value="DXV35_1test">
          <label for="DXV35_2test">Millennia Classic Brass test</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_2test" value="DXV35_2test">
          <label for="DXV35_3test">Millennia Full Brass test</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_3test" value="DXV35_3test">
        </div>  
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">am div3</div>

      </div>
      <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Installation</h3>
        <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>

      </div>
      <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Other Tab to Be Determined</h3>
        <p>Test data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link http://jsfiddle.net/w22L5nyo/

Comment: why are you breaking them out at all? Why not keep them all in the same container?

Comment: I have little experience with the mobile design which this project is for, so I am not sure if scrolling is a better choice versus a normal html form box area.

Comment: maybe I dont understand your question, but you're saying click products > then choose the first option...and then Tuscany Black and the rest are smaller and spaced out more than the above ones..right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were really intending on using the jQM grid to have the 2 lists side by side, then you simply left out the line: `<div class="ui-block-a">`

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
       //your radios for col 1
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        //your radios for col 2
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/w22L5nyo/6/)**

Also, you have a lot of extra, unnecessary DOM elements and some missing closing tags...

Comment: this is perfect, thank you, like I said I am new to code, about 1 week in. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

add float:left to css for ui-field-contain class  and remove top margin

```
              <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="float:left; margin:0px">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w22L5nyo/2/

Answer (score -1):

I may not fully understand your question, but why don't you just remove the div container with class `.ui-block-b` that separates the two sections and put them all in the same container like this:

```
   ...
   <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_9" value="DXV35_9">
   <label for="DXV35_10">Tuscany Black</label>
</div> //<-----------------------------------------------------------remove
<div class="ui-block-b"> //<-----------------------------------------remove
   <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_10" value="DXV35_10">
   <label for="DXV35_11">Tuscany Gold</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="modeltype" id="DXV35_11" value="DXV35_11">
   <label for="DXV35_12">Bentley Black Arch Screen Doors</label>
   ...
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w22L5nyo/3/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: you can remove the downvote now, I added some code, im fully aware of how to post an anwser, in this case there is alot of code and removing the small amount (which ive done) doesnt necessarily illustrate the issue. I included an explanation with my link originally anyways @DLeh